# have a capistrano task run for one recipe, but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have a chicken/egg situation with a directory that should exist for a before deploy:update_code task.

Is there any way to determine if cap deploy:cold was the calling recipe and have the task not run for that?  But for all others?  (cap deploy, cap deploy:migrations, whatever)

Right now, I'm using capture to determine if the directory exists on the server, but it would be ideal to not have to do that if it's not necessary.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Would your problem be solved by using a before hook on the deploy:update_code task? You could create a task the runs:

```
task :mkdir_for_update_code do
    mkdir -p /path_of_dir/
end
```

and then add

```
before 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:mkdir_for_update_code'
```

replacing the deploy in the second variable depending on which namespace the task is in.